# How does Arya get her dagger back in time?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In Game of Thrones, S08E03, *The Long Night*, [~18minutes into the episode]  Arya gives her Valyrian dagger to her sister, Sansa, as she tells her to go down to the crypt.  Confirmed [~47minutes in] when Arya uses Dragonglass, instead of the dagger, to kill the wight in the library. Only to have the dagger back in her hand(s) [~78minutes in] when she kills the Knight King. All with apparently no interactions in the crypts to regain the dagger from Sansa. Can anyone offer a reasonable explanation?

Comment: [Here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/211191/how-did-arya-get-her-dagger-back-from-sansa) is a cross-site duplicate over on scifi.

Comment: @Virusbomb I compared the image in your linked page to the one below, they are different scenes. The one below clearly shows a silver metal dagger, not Dragonglass.

Comment: This question seems based on the incorrect assumption that a character can only possess one weapon.  Yes, Arya used a dragonglass dagger in the library, but she also uses a dragonglass axe in the chase through the halls with Beric and the Hound.  Using those weapons does not prevent her from having the Valyrian steel dagger sheathed on her hip.

Comment: @krb Are you suggesting that Arya has more than one Valyrian dagger? Can you explain why Arya would bother picking up a Dragonglass dagger if she had the Valyrian dagger on her hip? What would be the point?

Comment: I found a clip of this online, [Arya passes the dagger to Sansa](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_U494Ij80c), and it does look more like a Dragonglass dagger. When I rewatched the show on HBO (and reran the clip then), it looked like the Valyrian dagger -- which is why I posed the quesiton. My bad.

Comment: @elbrant I did not say or even imply that she has more than one valyrian steel dagger and if you think I did then it's no wonder that you needed to ask a question about something that was obvious to everybody else. I said that people are able to carry more than one *weapon*. We know that she has the valyrian steel dagger. She was carrying a dragonglass dagger that she gave to Sansa. She killed a wight in the library with a different dragonglass dagger. She used her double-headed spear for a while. She used a dragonglass axe for while. She used a bow for a while.

Comment: Let's not put a massive spoiler into the question title, please.

Answer (score 7):

[It wasn't that dagger](https://time.com/5579377/game-of-thrones-arya-kill-night-king/):

> Some fans thought that Arya gave the dagger to Sansa at the beginning of the episode. After the wights proved unstoppable, Arya told Sansa to go down to the crypts and to take the dagger to protect herself. We only see the hilt and can assume it’s the Valyrian steel dagger. But **Sansa flashes the dagger to Tyrion in the crypts as they hide from the Wights and we see that it is dragonglass.**

Answer (score 3):

## Arya didn't give Sansa the catspaw dagger.

The dagger that Arya gave Sansa was just an "ordinary" dragonglass dagger.

Comment: For a better look at the dagger given to Sansa, at the :35 second mark of this video you can see that the blade is straight rather than curved and the edges are rough and uneven rather than smooth.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ToVOA3egMk

Comment: The (above) shot shows her handing Sansa the Valyrian dagger. That is not Dragonglass. The silver blade is in Arya's hand and Sansa's had is taking hold of the handle. If you were to back up just seconds before that, she pulls it from it's sheath on her belt.

Comment: @krb wrong scene

Comment: Wrong pic. This scene happens in s07, where Arya threatens Sansa & gives her the valyrian dagger. Please correct it

Comment: @elbrant a different scene but the one I linked shows the dagger that Sansa was given.